# Loading a bitmap takes more memory of the bitmap itself

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

I'm loading a 489KB bitmap using the BitmapFactory.decodeFile.

and I check how much memory my program takes after loading it and I see it adds ~5000KB

why is that, and what should I do to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bitmap is file is most likely compressed (PNG/JPG).
You can't expect that loaded bitmap will be still compressed in memory.
Each decompressed pixel in memory takes usually 4 bytes.

Comment: so what is the best way to load a png, and still be able to handle it like I can with a bitmap.

Comment: Why downvoting can anyone explains me what's wrong in his answer

Comment: did I need to ask my follow up question in a different post?

Comment: BitmapFactory.decodeFile is OK to load PNG file as Bitmap. But it will be decompressed, thus taking more memory than in file.
What else would you like to achieve?